# add a bitmap to a view in Android

Tags: android, view, bitmap, imageview

I have a vew, received by:
(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo)

That view currently has a bitmap on it. I want to add another bitmap, at the corner. The bitmap is retreieved by v.getDrawingCache(), from the listener I am currently in.Right now I have a code that completely replaces the image in the 'photo' view:

```
 OnClickListener mImageListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.buildDrawingCache();
            ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo)).setImageBitmap(v.getDrawingCache()); 
        }
    };
```

Doesanyone know how to just add the image? The answer on [Draw Bitmap When Still Using XML View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208140/draw-bitmap-when-still-using-xml-view) 
didn't really work for mefor some reason :(
Note: The bitmap I am adding will be moved around later on using a MoveListener or something. Just in case that was important...

Comment: what is adding at the corner ? can you explain a little more.

Comment: basically just add it somewhere so I can see it on top of the other image. Later on I will move it around. It doesn't really matter where I initially place it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use a SimView instead of an ImageView, it solved all the problems. Thanks for the help!

Comment: are you sure that you found the word SimView ?

Answer (score -1):

You can only associate one `bitmap` to one `ImageView`, it is a one to one mapping.

If you want another picture overlay'ed on top of the existing image then you will need to have both of them within a `FrameLayout`.

Also it will be easier for you to move around the smaller bitmap later on if it is in a different `ImageView`, acts as two different UI elements.

Sample pseudo xml

```
<RelativeLayout fill parent>
    <FrameLayout fill parent>
         <ImageView center in parent>
         <ImageView align bottom right = true>
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you sure about this? I've seen examples of view with multiple bitmaps on them, the difference was that all the bitmaps were drwan on the canvas when the view was created, and I want to draw them after the view is created. I think this should be done using a canvas or something. Also, I'll need to add a few bitmaps, not just one - will this option cover that?

Thanks!!

Comment: Drawing on a canvas by yourself is completely different, yes you can draw multiple bitmaps on a single canvas (actually you can draw anything you want) but the point is you are responsible for drawing it. But if you associate it with an `ImageView` you don't have to worry about drawing anything. Moving the view is also very simple capture touch events, get the x and y values, set the top and left of the image view and you are done.